# Pandas returns error: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem here, I was trying to find a specific value in my data frame. However I have received this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-245-ded282cec75c> in <module>
----> 1 data.iloc(data['Amount'] == '11,99')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __call__(self, axis)
    576 
    577         if axis is not None:
--> 578             axis = self.obj._get_axis_number(axis)
    579         new_self.axis = axis
    580         return new_self

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_axis_number(cls, axis)
    396     @classmethod
    397     def _get_axis_number(cls, axis):
--> 398         axis = cls._AXIS_ALIASES.get(axis, axis)
    399         if is_integer(axis):
    400             if axis in cls._AXIS_NAMES:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __hash__(self)
   1796 
   1797     def __hash__(self):
-> 1798         raise TypeError(
   1799             f"{repr(type(self).__name__)} objects are mutable, "
   1800             f"thus they cannot be hashed"

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

How can I proceed?

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', sep = ';')

data.iloc(data['Amount'] == '11,99')
```

Comment: Could you please try data[data['Amount'] == '11,99'] and tell. Also are you trying to compare Amount to multiple values or is '11,99' a value ?

Comment: Hi, it has worked as you described. You can imagine i have a csv file with transaction data and the amount is the amount for a specific transaction ID.

Comment: Kudos..Posting code snippet as answer too for reference..glad it worked..!

Answer (score 1):

Use `data[data['Amount'] == '11,99']`
It should work just fine..!